# Hide background until value change

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. I'd like to keep the background of this element hidden until the value change happens via the text input.
2. I'd like the width of the button to grow with the amount of text that is added (plus any additional padding). Right now it is automatically filling 100% of its parent container. I do not want this element to fill 100% of the width of its parent container.

Here is what I have now:

```js
var $divC = $('.button');

$('.buttonInput').bind('keyup change', function() {
    $divC.html(this.value);
    if(this.value.length > 0) {
           $('.button').css('display', 'block')
        } else {
           $('.button').css('display', 'none')
        }
});
```

```css
.button {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 110%;
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br>
<div class="button basic2"></div>
<br><br>
<form>Enter text:<br><input class="buttonInput"></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `margin: auto;` and `display: none;` to your button and use `display : table` to fit the width to the content

```js
var $divC = $('.button');

$('.buttonInput').bind('keyup change', function() {
    $divC.html(this.value);
    if(this.value.length > 0) {
           $('.button').css('display', 'table')
        } else {
           $('.button').css('display', 'none')
        }
});
```

```css
.button {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 110%;
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center; 
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br>
<div class="button basic2"></div>
<br><br>
<form>Enter text:<br><input class="buttonInput"></form>
```